# Upload Video using wordpress rest api with ionic

Tags: uploads, rest-api, media

Hello I am trying to upload the video to wordpress with ionic app using wordpress rest api

I follow this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMEkHYjuxSU

here is my code

```
    uploadFileWP(URL){
    console.log('uploadFileWP', URL)
    let fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();
    let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('wpIonicToken')).token;
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=appVideo.mp4",
        //'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=\'video.mp4\'"
      }
   }
 
   fileTransfer.upload(URL, 'http://wordpress-url/wp-json/wp/v2/media', options)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

here `URL` is path to video in my phone

I got this error

```
    FileTransferError {
    body: "{\"code\":\"rest_upload_unknown_error\",\"message\":\"Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.\",\"data\":{\"status\":500}}"
    code: 1
    exception: "http://wordpress-url/wp-json/wp/v2/media"
    http_status: 500
    source: "file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/my_media/1621071105012.mp4"
    target: "http://wordpress-url/wp-json/wp/v2/media"
  }
```

with the same code I can upload the Image successfully
I also add `define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);` in `wp-config.php`

Comment: If you upload the same video to WordPress directly, does it work?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes